# PhantomJS crashing on windows due to memory leak after ~1000 tests. Would it be possible to separate the tests into buckets of ~500 and run that?

Tags: javascript, gulp, phantomjs, tdd, karma-runner

Where would this be done if its possible? Are there some workarounds? I am using gulp and karma here.

I have tried installing the phantom js2 binary, adding it to my path, and adding the dev dependency in my package.json, no luck.

There is a lot of code so i can add relevant snippets as necessary depending on the workarounds discussed.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a duplicate of [How to get around memory error with karma & phantomjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239708/how-to-get-around-memory-error-with-karma-phantomjs) , it is a known bug of PhantomJS 1.

You may use a different gulp karma runner plugin (I succeeded with this https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-phantomjs2-launcher).

Splitting the tests might into smaller batches should also work around the bug, but if you gather code coverage, you will have to combine the results.